# Event for Markup drawing

Tags: events, autodesk-forge, markup

What is the name of event when we start drawing the markup(circle, arrow, rectangle etc.) on the shape when in edit mode? And can we change the markup type in this event?

Problem is: When we are in edit mode and have selected specific shape and color to draw the markup, and in between if we select any markup, the drawing tool takes up that shape and color for the next markup to be drawn ignoring the markup type and color we selected earlier. Is this the normal behavior. Why does the drawing tool take up the configuration of the last selected markup and overrides the type we define through - new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EditModeCloud(markupExt);
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting question. I believe the current behavior of markups is as-designed because one would typically only select a markup if they wanted to move it around, scale it, etc. That's why in the current implementation, selecting a markup automatically enters its edit mode.

At the same time I understand your view where if I already activate a specific edit mode, it seems strange that that edit mode would change after simply selecting another markup.

Let me bring this up with the engineering team, and in the meantime, I'd suggest using the `Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EVENT_EDITMODE_CHANGED` event to detect a change to the edit mode, and if needed, reset the mode to the one you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this request. Will surely look into the suggested event to reset the selected markup mode. Though look forward for your findings on this topic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When we use the Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EVENT_EDITMODE_CHANGED to detect the change and change the edit mode in this event, it throws call stack error in https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/Markup/Markup.min.js. Please suggest.   markupExt.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EVENT_EDITMODE_CHANGED, (result)=>{if(result.target.type !== _self._markupType) {
                       markupExt.changeEditMode(markupDrawType);
                        markupExt.setStyle(this._styleObject);
                    }});

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue. I assume that `_self._markupType` does not get updated properly to the new style you want to use BEFORE calling `markupExt.changeEditMode()` that will trigger the same event handler straight away resulting in infinite recursion.